# cannot resolve symbol Builder android

Tags: java, android

This is my code for posting data to Google Forms. I used OkHTTP3 for sending request.

```
okhttp3.Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
```

In the above code, it shows cannot resolve symbol Builder.

I have also imported the below packages

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
```

and included the below package in the gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

Comment: Try also to add [`import okhttp3.Request`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Request.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
okhttp3.Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
```

with

```
okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
```

It should work.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to implement your answer but all Android Studio 3 prompts me to add is newBuilder(). I tried googling for answers but they only leave me more confused - are Builder() and newBuilder() the same?

Comment: newBuilder is not static, its accessed via request object. while Builder is a static class and can be accessed directly.

Comment: Got it. I figured out that I have to call Builder by using the full package name as otherwise it defaults to the Request package from Volley, which I was using earlier. 

Now I say okhttp3.Request.Builder() ....  :)